# How to get the selected text from webview?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

If I holds the finger on a word displayed in web view,
highlight the word with corner anchors to allow
me to stretch the selection across a span of
words. Once a block of text is
highlighted, it gives me the option to copy text.

Can i get that highlighted text without coping it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one worked for me: [Cocobuilder archive](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/164158-selected-string-in-webview.html?q=webview+selected+text#164158)

In short, you need:

```
[[myWebView selectedDOMRange] toString];
```